# blazor.server.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/_blazor?id=vCfY6WQKquNRSMNHPn094Q' failed

Tags: blazor

I have created an ASP.NET Core Blazor server-side application. It works well on IIS Express when I debug it with Visual Studio but when I publish it to IIS, it cant read data from my SQL SERVER database. it gives two errors:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/_blazor?id=vCfY6WQKquNRSMNHPn094Q' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value
>
> Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': undefined

I can't figure out why it works on IIS express,but not works on IIS?

Comment: i changed my connection string from trusted connection to standart security, and now it can read data, in the chrome developer tools console,there is still the same errors.